# Find system user that uses mail address on webserver - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, postfix-mta

I have a user that uses his mail address on multiple web servers and multiple websites.
On one of our servers, we keep seeing that one of his websites is sending out spam with the mail address.
But how do I figure witch website/system user that uses the mail address?

Hope my explanation makes sense or feel free to ask questions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right i figured it out. Here is what i did.

Run  `mailq` note the Queue ID

Afterwards run `zgrep "Queue ID" /var/log/mail.log*`

Then look for the uid eg `/var/log/mail.log:Feb  5 10:25:58 web3 postfix/pickup[31936]: B59851300B90: uid=1004 from=<mailadress@eksempel.dk>` = Uid 1004

List all users and their user id's `awk -F: '($3 >= 1000) {printf "%s:%s\n",$1,$3}' /etc/passwd`

Then you have the user.

Hope this can help someone out there :)